# Plot square signal from binary array [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot the two signals in Python (Spyder). Bellow, I have indicated photos of the signal that my code needs to plot. (The first one I manage to plot it successfully.)

[image]

However, I am not able to plot the square signal from the array word [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1].

[image]

Can someone help me to figure out how to plot the above signal?

```
import fft_modules
from fft_modules import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, linspace, sin, cos, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy import *


A=1                                                 
f=1000
T=1/f                                          
B=f                                            
Nyquist_Fs=2*B                                 
Fs=100*Nyquist_Fs                              
Ts=T/10                                        
Tmax=25*T                                      
samples_per_period=T/Ts                        
total_samples=samples_per_period*(Tmax/T)      

print("TS="+str(Ts))
print("T="+str(T))

t = linspace(0, Tmax, total_samples, endpoint=True)

#our_signal = signal.square(A*cos(2*pi*f*t))
our_signal = A*sin(2*pi*f*t)


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,our_signal)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')
#plt.ylim(-1, 1)
#plt.grid('on')


word = array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
Samples_per_bit=int(12/Ts)
pliroforia=[]
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    table=np.ones(Samples_per_bit)
    x=table*word[i]
    pliroforia=np.concatenate((pliroforia,x))

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t,pliroforia)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [matplotlib step](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) function instead of plot.

```
import numpy as NP
import pylab as plt
plt.figure(2)
#Padded data with a zero so it looks like your plot.
word = NP.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
plt.step(NP.arange(0, len(word)), word)
```

[image: Example step image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution where you generate each point of the graph:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

word =  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

# for proper scaling
const = 48000

graph_data_x = []
graph_data_y = []
for i in range(len(word)):
    graph_data_x.append(i / const)
    graph_data_x.append((i + 1) / const)
    graph_data_y.append(word[i])
    graph_data_y.append(word[i])


plt.plot(graph_data_x, graph_data_y)
```

gives you exactly what you need

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have two arrays with different sizes.
Try the following code:

```
import fft_modules
from fft_modules import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, linspace, sin, cos, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy import *


A=1                                                 
f=1000
T=1/f                                          
B=f                                            
Nyquist_Fs=2*B                                 
Fs=100*Nyquist_Fs                              
Ts=T/10                                        
Tmax=25*T                                      
samples_per_period=T/Ts                        
total_samples=samples_per_period*(Tmax/T)      

print("TS="+str(Ts))
print("T="+str(T))

t = linspace(0, Tmax, total_samples, endpoint=True)

#our_signal = signal.square(A*cos(2*pi*f*t))
our_signal = A*sin(2*pi*f*t)


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,our_signal)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')
#plt.ylim(-1, 1)
#plt.grid('on')


word = array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
Samples_per_bit=int(12/Ts)
pliroforia=[]
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    table=np.ones(Samples_per_bit)
    x=table*word[i]
    pliroforia=np.concatenate((pliroforia,x))

t = linspace(0, Tmax, pliroforia.shape[0], endpoint=True)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t,pliroforia)
plt.xlabel('Χρόνος (sec) ->')
plt.ylabel ('Πλάτος (V)')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code seems to work perfectly. However, eventually, I need to generate the following ASK signal from the 2 above.        Indicated plot : [link](https://imgur.com/a/ugS4W1x)

---- The code for that should be :

`ASK_signal=pliroforia*our_signal    
plt.figure(3)     
plt.plot(t,ASK_signal)`       


---But I am receiving the following error: 

--ASK_signal=pliroforia*our_signal          

--ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1440000,) (250,)

Comment: It looks like you are having problems with different shapes. I would advise you to open a new question focused on this other case. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.